# NASM Assembly while loop counter

Tags: c, loops, gcc, assembly, nasm

I'm writing a while loop in assembly to compile in the Linux terminal with nasm and gcc. The program compares x and y until y >= x and reports number of loops at the end. Here's the code:

```
segment .data

out1    db "It took ", 10, 0
out2    db "iterations to complete loop. That seems like a lot.", 10, 0
x       db 10
y       db 2
count   db 0

segment .bss

segment .text

global main
extern printf

main:
    mov    eax, x
    mov    ebx, y
    mov    ecx, count
    jmp    lp         ;jump to loop lp

lp:
    cmp    ebx, eax   ;compare x and y
    jge    end        ;jump to end if y >= x
    inc    eax        ;add 1 to x
    inc    ebx        ;add 2 to y
    inc    ebx
    inc    ecx        ;add 1 to count
    jp     lp         ;repeat loop

end:

    push    out1      ;print message part 1
    call    printf

    push    count     ;print count
    call    printf

    push    out2      ;print message part 2
    call    printf

    ;mov    edx, out1               ;
    ;call   print_string            ;
                                    ;
    ;mov    edx, ecx                ;these were other attempts to print
    ;call   print_int               ;using an included file
                                    ;
    ;mov    edx, out2               ;
    ;call   print_string            ;
```

This is compiled and run in the terminal with:

```
nasm -f elf test.asm
gcc -o test test.o
./test
```

Terminal output comes out as:

```
It took
iterations to complete loop. That seems like a lot.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I can't see anything wrong with the logic. I think it's syntactical but we've only just started learning assembly and I've tried all sorts of different syntax like brackets around variables and using `ret` at the end of a segment, but nothing seems to work. I've also searched for segmentation faults but I haven't found anything really helpful. Any help would be appreciated because I'm an absolute beginner.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason it crashes is probably that your `main` function doesn't have a `ret` instruction. Also be sure to set `eax` to 0 to signal success:

```
xor     eax, eax ; or `mov eax, 0` if you're more comfortable with that
ret
```

Additionally, global variables designate pointers, not values. `mov eax, x` sets `eax` to the address of `x`. You need to write back to it if you want anything to happen (or not use global variables).

Finally, you're calling `printf` with a single non-string argument:

```
push    count     ;print count
call    printf
```

The first argument needs to be a format string, like `"%i"`. Here, `count` is a pointer to a null byte, so you get nothing instead. Off my head, you should try this:

```
out3    db "%i ", 0

; snip

push    ecx
push    out3
call    printf
```

Comment: Awesome help, thank you, output is now `It took 134520932 iterations... a lot.` Could you explain more about writing back to eax in this context? Using `mov eax, [x]` didn't help like I thought it might. Also, I added `mov eax, 0` and `ret` at the end of main, but still get the segmentation fault, any ideas? Also, would you mind explaining the purpose of `mov eax, 0` and `ret`?

Comment: Just like that, no. Consider using `gdb` to find out where it's crashing. (Also, I just noticed that you're using `jp` to jump back. Are you sure that you don't mean `jmp`?)

Comment: For `mov eax, 0` then `ret`, it's because otherwise, there's no instruction to tell your program to end. Execution will continue with zero bytes (which mean like `add al, 0` or something) until it reaches the end of the allocated memory, and then it crashes. When a function return, its result is expected to sit in `eax`, so we're basically saying "return 0" here, if you have any notion of C.

Comment: As for `134520932`, it looks an awful lot like a memory address. You should probably get rid of your global variables `x`, `y` and `count` and only use registers.

Comment: Okay, the `eax` and `ret` thing makes perfect sense, thanks. I've eliminated `x`, `y` and `count` and am just using registers, but it seems I do have some sort of problem with the loop because `ecx` (count register) is returning 0. You've been tons of help, I think I can work it out from here. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem might just be that you are referencing the addresses of your constants and not their intrinsic value. One must think of a label in nasm as a pointer rather than a value. To access it you just need to use `[label]`:

```
 segment .data
     x      dw 42
 segment .text
     global main
     extern printf
 main:
     mov    eax, x
     push   eax
     call   printf   ; will print address of x (like doing cout<<&x in C++)
     mov    eax, [x]
     push   eax
     call   printf   ; will print 42
     sub    esp, 8
     xor    eax, eax
     ret
```

PS:I don't think anyone has mentioned it but volatile registers are modified very often when calling external code (C or C++ or other) since at compilation those functions you use are "translated" to assembly and then linked with your asm file. The PC is not a human so it is not distinguishing between what was written in high-level or low-level, the processor is just reading opcodes and operands stored in registers and memory, hence why an external function when using low-level language (`call printf`) is going to modify (or not! always depends on compiler and architecture) registers that you are also using.
To solve this there are various solutions:

1. You check what registers are not being modified by using `gcc your_c_file.c -S` and then in the file `your_c_file.s`will be the pre-prepared assembly code your compiler has produced from your C file. (It tends to be quite hard to figure out what is what and if you are going to use this method check out Name Mangling, to see how func names will be changed.)
2. Push all the registers you want to save to stack, and then after the call pop them back to their registers keeping in mind LIFO method.
3. Use the instructions `PUSHA` and `POPA`which push or pop all registers respectively.

This is the NASM manual chapter 3 which explains the basis of the language to use: http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~comp03/nasm/nasmdoc3.html

Hope you managed to solve it.